# Php, static variables for trait itself only, how?

Tags: php

its possible to have static variables for traits:

```
Trait Example
{
    public static $var;
}

class X
{
    use Example;
}

class Y
{
    use Example;
}
```

however, the problem is when more class would want to use this trait, I get a fatal error:

```
Example and X define the same property ($var) in the composition of Y. This might be incompatible, to improve maintainability consider using accessor methods in traits instead. Class was composed
```

how to define this static variable just for the trait itself?

Answer (score 4):

Traits can define both static members and static methods. however You can not reassign trait properties.

From PHP manual http://php.net/traits

See Example #12 Conflict Resolution

> If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property with the same name, otherwise an error is issued. It is an E_STRICT if the class definition is compatible (same visibility and initial value) or fatal error otherwise.

The solution would be to override properties in the class

```
 Trait Example
{
    public static $var;
}

class X
{
    use Example;
    public static $var;
}

class Y
{
    use Example;
    public static $var;
}
```

Comment: Which version of php?